# Decoding a regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to decode the following Perl regular expression:

```
$fname =~ /\/([^\/]+)\.txt$/
```

What are we trying to match for here?

Comment: The Perl module `YAPE::Regex::Explain` can tell you, as long as your regexp isn't using some of the more advanced constructs of Perl 5.10 or newer:  Read the output of `$ perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -E 'say YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(q{\/([^\/]+)\.txt$})->explain'`  You can fetch that module from CPAN.

Comment: Note, it's helpful to use a different regex delimiter when working with the file system so one doesn't end up with a bunch of leaning towers like this.  I'd write the above as: `$fname =~ m{/([^/]+)\.txt$}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you break it down.

- `\/` - the literal character `/`
- `(...)` - followed by a group that will be captured to `$1`

  - `[ ... ]` - a character class

    - `^` - in a character class, this means take the inversion of the specified set
    - `\/` - the literal character `/`
  - `+` - one or more times
- `\.`  - the literal character `.`
- `txt` - the literal string `txt`
- `$` - the end of the string

So, in other words, this is trying to match "anything with a `/` followed by one or more characters that are *not* `/`, followed by `.txt`, followed by the end of the string, and put the part before `.txt` into `$1`"

Answer (score 3):

```
\/([^\/]+)\.txt
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression matches a file name, as it exists in a path

- Minus the extension, and
- Only when (or starting *where*) the path begins with an up-right slash.

Examples:

```
\folder\path\file.txt
```

Nothing is matched.

```
folder/path/file.txt
```

`file.txt` is matched (and `file` is placed in capture group 1: `$1`).

```
/folder/path/file.txt
```

Again, `file.txt` is matched (and `file` captured).

You can [try it yourself at Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6G0hMDYRa47iGA5h)

Comment: It does not match the path with backslashes. The backslashes only escape the slashes. As your Debuggex image also shows.

Comment: Actually, the regex does not match backslash. That is an escaped slash, not a backslash and a slash.

Comment: Well... While you are right about what your shortened regex matches, the one in the OP requires a slash right before the capture group.

Comment: @DeVadder: Grumble grumble grumble. I misunderstood the first up-right slashes to be the this-is-a-regex Perl operators. FIXED!!!